# Typescript cast array of object to a linear type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm a beginner in the fabulous world of type creation in typescript and I have a little problem.

I have a array of obects

```js
type foo = [
  {name:"aa", type:"string", usless:"cc", ...},
  {name:"aaaa", type:"number", ...},
  {name:"aaa", usless:"cc", ...}
]
```

my goal is to transform my type foo to a reduce one

```js
type reduceFoo = transformArray<foo>
//    ^? {name:"aa",type:string}|{name:"aaaa",type:number}|{name:"aaa"}
```

One of the tricky things is that when the `type` attribute is not defined, I want it not to be in the final type.

I tried to loop on foo with `{[U in foo]:Pick<U,'name'|'type'>}` but this is not the right way to do it

And finally I have a function that transforms a string into a type (`stringToType<T:string>`) but I want to apply it only on the type attribute of the object. But I have no idea when to call him

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX7DkW)?  If that meets your needs I could maybe post an answer. But your last paragraph isn't making a lot of sense to me, so you might want to elaborate.  What does `stringToType<T:string>` mean? It's not valid syntax. Can you define it for us?

Comment: Thanks ! For the second part, I found a way to do what I want : [K in keyof T as Extract<K, 'name' | 'type'>]: K extends 'type' ? StringToType<T[K]> : T[K]